# My clock disappeared from my lock screen on my Galaxy A50

Tags: samsung, clock

I have a Samsung Galaxy A50. I've been messing with it a bunch with ADB, uninstalling apps. I do not have root access. Recently, I was just sitting there, listening to music on it, when it suddenly shut down. When I turned it back on, the clock was gone from the lock screen. If i swipe through the "face widgets," the time will appear in the top bar, and it's there in the top bar when I unlock my phone too. It is just missing from the "face widget" on the lock screen. When I go into settings > lock screen, tapping "clock style" does literally nothing.
I am guessing this is a result of something I uninstalled, but which built-in app could it be? And why did this only happen several days after uninstalling stuff?